# can you do two string methods in an if statement?

Tags: python, string, methods

I'm trying to get this to work.

So if `variableX` is a letter or if it is more than 3 digits long the if statement will activate.

```
if variableX.isalpha() == True or if len(variable) > 3:
```

Comment: `if variableX.isalpha() or len(variable) > 3:`

Answer (score 0):

Almost there, just lose the second if:

```
if variableX.isalpha() or len(variableX) > 3:
```

You can also lose the `== True` part of `.isalpha()`, because the function will already return `True` or `False`.

Answer (score -1):

i fixed a second later FML

if variableX.isalpha() == True or if len(variable) > 3:

i just got rid of the 2nd if

if variableX.isalpha() == True or len(variable) > 3: